# Can CDI inject standard library POJOs into an EJB?

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I can inject my own POJO into a managed object like this:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
@Stateless
public class SomeEjb {
    @Inject
    private SomePojo somePojo;
}
```

And I have this POJO:

```
// No annotations
public class SomePojo {   
}
```

This works fine. If I inject the EJB into a JSF backing-bean, I can see that the value of `somePojo` is non-null value, as expected.

However, if I try to inject a `java.util.Date` into `SomeEjb`, I get the following exception on deployment:

```
Severe: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Date] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private SomeEjb.date]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Date] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private SomeEjb.date]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
```

SomeEjb now:

```
// No annotations
public class SomeEjb {
    @Inject
    private Date date;    
}
```

Date has a public, no-argument constructor, and I thought that's all CDI would need to "satisfy the dependency". I'm sure this behaviour is "to spec", but clearly there's a big hole in my understanding of CDI.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work? What's the difference between `SomePojo` and `java.util.Date` from a CDI perspective?

Context:

- Java EE 6
- GlassFish 3.1.2.2
- I don't have a use-case for this. I know that I can just specify `new Date()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this with EAP 6.3 as well.

The problem most likely occurs because of using Java EE 6. The java.util.Date is located in rt.jar and this JAR does not contain a beans.xml file which would enable CDI. You can only inject objects from JARs containing a beans.xml.

A common workaround is to use a [producer method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjdid.html) to inject such an object. You have to wirte this producer yourself but you will be able to inject objects from arbitrary classes regardless to which JAR they belong.

As far as I know the behaviour changed in Java EE 7, where the beans.xml is  optional in some cases: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/default_cdi_enablement_in_java

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll try this out in Glassfish 4 in a day or two and report back. Thank you.

Comment: EE7 isn't going to change the behavior in this particular case.  With CDI 1.1 it will automatically discover beans with a bean defining annotation (see section 12.4 Bean Discovery of the spec).  Date does not have a bean defining annotation (such as @RequestScoped)

Comment: @jbergmark, I found a reference to what you're describing in the [Bean Archive](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive) section of the spec: "An implicit bean archive is any other archive which contains one or more bean classes with a bean defining annotation..." This is actually also alluded to in the blog post roehrijn referenced: "By default, if you specify nothing and there is no beans.xml, the bean discovery mode of 'annotated' and not 'all' is assumed." Thanks!

Comment: I tried two things, and they both worked: (1) add an `@Produces` method to produce `Date` objects, and (2) add a copy of the `java.util.Date` class to my project. I realize the second approach is odd, but it satisfied my curiosity. I assume I could also repackage `rt.jar` with a `beans.xml` file, and then I could inject any STL POJO. The first approach is the only one I would ever use, but this has been very instructive.

Comment: @DavidS: Doing the latter will definitly cause a lot of additional problems and exceptions. You're right - just never ever do this and use (1).